# Universally measurable sets and the perfect set property

Tags: descriptive-set-theory, measure-theory

Is it true that all universally measurable sets (say on   $[0,1]$   ) have the perfect set property?
I am not an expert in this at all and the answer may be known, but I was not able to find it.
I know that all Borel, analytic, and projective sets have the perfect set property and are universally measurable
but in such generality the answer to my question may be false.

Comment: Are you working in ZFC?  If so, you can take any uncountable universally null set as a counterexample.  If it contained a continuous injective image of $2^\omega$, you'd be able to push forward the product measure to contradict its universally nullness (nullity?).

Comment: Perhaps the "perfect set property" is: given any nonzero finite measure $\mu$ on the sigma-algebra, there is a perfect set $F$ with $\mu(F)>0$.

Comment: I guess also require $\mu$ to be atomless.

Comment: I assumed perfect set property meant the standard thing, although in retrospect it's somewhat suspicious that projective sets are claimed to possess it.  (Also I wish we could edit comments -- I was so thrown by "nullness" vs. "nullity" that I forgot to demote "universally" from adverb to adjective.)

Comment: Perhaps the question's assertion that projective sets are all universally measurable and have the PSP means that Detelin wants to assume projective determinacy.

Comment: Well as mentioned above, it a theorem of ZFC that the answer is "no, since there's an uncountable universally null set."  If Detelin is not assuming at least ZFC, some clarification is in order.

Comment: Apparently, should have been more precise when stating the question.
I am assuming ZFC. For the question I have asked, a set is having PSP if it is either countable or contains a perfect subset.
So, apparently in ZFC the answer is NO since, as Clinton mentioned, there are universally null sets.
Thanks.